How to add new line inisde .razor file for .net web application
Impact    <    span title="Impact 1 \n Impact 2" class="tooltip-target InfoIconMrgn"    >
I tried using style="white-space:pre-line", , and using unicode like also, still no progress.
I am using dotnet framework with C# language and telerik blazor.

Razor is used for a lot of Telerik products such as MVC, Asp.net Core & Blazor. Hard to point you in the right direction without knowing what product you're using. But, basically search for 'Telerik  MVC Tooltip Custom Template' https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/html-helpers/layout/tooltip/razor-page

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
